# DoubleClick Floodlight onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, double-click, google-floodlight

I'm trying to convert the following code into a "onClick" event to add to a HREF tag. I have limited JavaScript experience, but I know it can be done. Any sort of guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe src="https://4607507.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=4607507;type=ustac0;cat=lwt16db;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
</script>
<noscript>
<iframe src="https://4607507.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=4607507;type=ustac0;cat=lwt16db;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Floodlight documentation](https://support.google.com/dfa/partner/answer/134533?hl=en) explains how to accomplish something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="DoubleClickFloodlightTag">
    //<![CDATA[
    function FLOOD1(type, cat, u1) {
            var axel = Math.random()+"";
            var a = axel * 10000000000000000;
            var flDiv=document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            flDiv.setAttribute("id","DCLK_FLDiv1");
            flDiv.style.position="absolute";
            flDiv.style.top="0";
            flDiv.style.left="0";
            flDiv.style.width="1px";
            flDiv.style.height="1px";
            flDiv.style.display="none";
            flDiv.innerHTML='<iframe id="DCLK_FLIframe1" src="http://12345678.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=12345678;type=' + type + ';cat=' + cat + ';u1=' + u1 + ';ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"><\/iframe>';
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- This is an example of a "onclick" call on a anchor tag -->
     <a href="http://address_of_page_to_load_or_file_to_download" onclick="FLOOD1('testtype', 'testcat', 'testu1');" target="_blank">Click here to test the tag</a>
</body>
```

This should mostly get you there, but will also need to customize `flDiv.innerHTML` and the `onclick()` function with the appropriate Floodlight string values for your project.